# Check sum values in a select

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, select

I need a validation before submitting this form:

```
    <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" id="form1" name="contract">
<table class="myp-table">
<tr>
<td>Value Test</td> 
</tr>
 <?php do { ?>
<tr>
<td><select name="playerContract[]">
                    <option value="0" <?php if (!(strcmp(0, $row_datacontract['playerContract']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>0</option>
                    <option value="1" <?php if (!(strcmp(1, $row_datacontract['playerContract']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>1</option>
                    <option value="2" <?php if (!(strcmp(2, $row_datacontract['playerContract']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>2</option>
                    <option value="3" <?php if (!(strcmp(3, $row_datacontract['playerContract']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>3</option>
                  </select></td>
</tr>
<?php } while ($row_datacontract = mysql_fetch_assoc($datacontract)); ?>
 <tr>
<td><input class="linkbuttonmp" name="contract" type="submit" value="Invio" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

The sum of the values selected by users mustn't exceed the default value which in my case is a value retrieved from my database.

I tried with jquery in this way:

```
 var max = 3;

$("#form1 select").change(function () {

    var selects = <?php echo $row_datacoach['coachContract']; ?>;

    $("#form1 select").each(function () {

        selects = selects + parseInt($(this).val());

    });


    if(selects >= max) { 
        $("#submit").attr("disabled","disabled");
    } else {
        $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    }

});
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Can you help me?

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I made a mistake: the following is the script I actually tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var max = <?php echo $row_datacoach['coachContract']; ?>;

$("#form1 select").change(function () {

    var selects = 0;

    $("#form1 select").each(function () {

        selects = selects + parseInt($(this).val());

    });


    if(selects >= max) { 
        $("#submit").attr("disabled","disabled");
    } else {
        $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    }

});
</script>
```

Comment: Your form doesn't have an ID `

Comment: Once you fix the ID, note that the `.prop()` method is a better choice than `.attr()` for this purpose, especially since you can simplify to `$("#submit").prop("disabled", selects >= max);`. (I hope you provide some instructions telling the user why the submit button might get disabled, or what they'd need to do to re-enable it...)

Comment: @nnnnnn - was just typing that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value fetched from database need to be assigned to variable `max` and the `selects` has to be initialized with value `0`.

I think it should be

```
var max = <?php echo $row_datacoach['coachContract']; ?>;

$("#form1 select").change(function () {
    var selects = 0;
    $("#form1 select").each(function () {
        selects = selects + parseInt($(this).val());
    });

    if(selects >= max) { 
        $("#submit").attr("disabled","disabled");
    } else {
        $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    }

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/X5nSC/)

Answer (score 0):

add ID to form :

```
<form action="" method="POST" name="contract" id="form1">
```

then do :

```
var max = 3;

$("#form1 select").on('change', function () {
    var selects = 0;
    $("#form1 select").each(function () {
        selects += parseInt(this.value, 10);
    });

    $("#submit").prop('disabled', selects >= max);
});
```

Comment: You're right, I forgot to add the id in the form. I tried what you suggested but it didn't work